Enable extension only WSL?
I'm running Win11 with WSL.  I'm wondering if there is a way to have an extension only enabled when connecting to WSL?
For a bit more context, I'm testing Mojo which only has installs for Linux and Mac currently.  I installed Mojo into my WSL2 (Ubuntu) and added the Mojo extension in VS code, but the extension complains when I'm opening projects on Win11 (which is expected since Mojo paths don't exist on Windows).
I'm wondering if there is a way to tell VS Code, only enable/run this extension when I connect to WSL?
Thank you.

VS Code feature request should be posted to GitHub https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues but you can always set up a profile for WSL manually, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles
